# Play Video In Qt from BYTE* Stream?

Tags: c++, qt, video, streaming

I want to display video in Qt from Byte* stream which is I am getting from an C++ library. The video is coming  from Astrisk server in VP8 format. I am able to get Byte* Stream from it in Qt now i want to display it in Qt window I am also getting all the information of video like frame rate, size, width, height. etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a `QByteArray` of the byte stream, provide a `QBuffer` from the `QByteArray` and pass the buffer as the stream for a `QMediaPlayer` :

```
databuf = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(array), size);
QBuffer mediaStream(&databuf);

player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), &buffer);

videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
videoWidget->show();

player->play();
```