# How to save a .h264 stream to an image? C++

Tags: c++, image, file, video, h.264

ALREADY WORKING:
I get video from embedded video source (just device) through LAN and I can get video from it and save it to file ".h264" (append to file every next "encodedPacket", C++) (it is worked fine, I can play file using VLC).

TASK:
How can I save image files periodically (5 in 1 second for example) (any format, but I want jpg)?

File info:

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.1
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, RefFrames               : 1 frame
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive

Comment: Here there is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800772/how-to-grab-video-frames-in-qt

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  You say about "You can use QMediaPlayer to achieve this."? QMediaPlayer can get data from char* packet?

Comment: and here the answer about this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749105/play-video-in-qt-from-byte-stream

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is your friend:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

I'd try something like: ffmpeg -i input.h264 -vf fps=5 out%d.jpg

If your input is a network stream you can do something like ffmpeg -i tcp://local_hostname:port?listen

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Comment: Great! But how can I route my stream from my program to ffmpeg not via file?

Comment: How is the video transported? PLEASE tell us the format.

Comment: I don't understand your question :( What does you mean?     Video Format : AVC Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec Format profile : Baseline@L3.1 Format settings : 1 Ref Frames Format settings, CABAC : No Format settings, RefFrames : 1 frame Width : 640 pixels Height : 480 pixels Display aspect ratio : 4:3 Color space : YUV Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 Bit depth : 8 bits Scan type : Progressive

Comment: You are getting your video over LAN. So is it TCP, UDP, RTP, RTMP, DASH, HLS or some other transport format. Your H.264 stream gets transported from one computer to another. What is the mode of network transportation?

Comment: I get it from device via UDP using private protocol (protocol by device's developer).

Comment: When I try to use your ffmpeg methos with my file i see this (no jpg files was created): https://ibb.co/eq4VZm

Comment: Please share your input file test.264.

Comment: But I want to create image with no creation of video file. I have an stream to file, I want to send it to ffmpeg to do images. Is it possible?